# Storing Key to JVM for days

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

For a web application I am fetching a secret key from DB and I want to hit the DB only once.
For every login, I want to use stored key without hitting the DB again.
I can't store the key on server or properties file.
How can i use JVM for this so that key can be stored and fetched and also flushed after 10 days.

Comment: I know you must have some twist in this problem, but it is hard to spot it. Why would not you just put all your user/key pairs (or just that single (?) key) to a hashmap and call it done? Maybe your answer were reveal the secret twist.

Comment: Yeah, I think you just want to store it in a local variable - maybe storing it as a char array instead of String (see https://www.baeldung.com/java-storing-passwords)